# regex find and replace a specific attribute from a specific tag eclipse

Tags: regex, eclipse

I am trying to replace the attribute(label) to (header) in tag(rich:panel) by using eclipse File Search.

```
    <rich:panel type="a" label="b">
```

to

```
    <rich:panel type="a" header="b">
```

I use regex below which is able to find an replace the attribute value but I need to replace attribute. Any idea?

```
(rich:panel[^>]*label\s*=\s*")[^"]*
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

REgex:

```
(rich:panel[^>]*)\blabel(\s*=)
```

REplacement string:

```
$1header$2
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/pE1fJ0/5)

Comment: It works well for me and the demo website is pretty nice to have a testing. Thank you so much. I am really new for regex, does any material or reference I can learn from? If you can offer it, that will be awesome. Thank you again.

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/ great site which covers all types of regex notations and also read answers of great regex people.